# How can I put a podcast on my USB device?

Tags: finder, usb, podcasts

I have running headphones that I connect to my Mac via USB (they mount as an external volume).  I can't figure out how to download podcasts onto them. When I try dragging the file from the "Downloaded" section of the Podcasts app into the relevant folder in Finder, nothing happens.  When I try dragging the file from the "Your Episodes" section of Spotify, it seems like a soft-link back to spotify is the thing that get's pasted.

I feel like I used to do this no problem?

Further information: Mac is 2020 MacBook Pro, macOS 11.4, Podcast app is version 1.1.0.  Headphones are old Sony Walkman, but they mount just fine and I can pull up the folder in Finder where I want to move the podcast file to.

I would be happy to drag the file from one finder window to another, but I don't see where the Podcast app actually stores the files in Finder and there's no "show in Finder" option when I right click the episode in the Podcat app.

Comment: We'll need a few details: make/model of headphones, Mac you are using, version of macOS on your Mac. And if you are dragging out of a podcast app that *may* not work. you may need to drag the podcast file itself from one finder window to where it needs to go. But if you fill us in on the details (please **EDIT** your original question) we may be able to help

Comment: The current Podcast app does not feature an export function anymore. I did find this workaround, but haven't tried it myself: https://douglas-watson.github.io/post/2020-05_export_podcasts/

Answer (score 1):

Podcasts stores downloaded files at this location in Finder:

`~/Library/Group Containers/243LU875E5.groups.com.apple.podcasts/Library/Cache`

(You can access this by using "Go to Folder" option in Finder, which is <kbd>Command+Shift+G</kbd>)

Unfortunately, these episodes are not labeled with the episode name. If you open the file in [VLC](https://www.videolan.org/vlc/), however, the embedded data will be visible. Once you find the file you'd like, you can *copy* it to any location you'd like.

Comment: oh, how baroque!  But it does seem to work...